# MonoDevelop ASP.NET parser error using inline server tags inside html tag attribute

Tags: asp.net, macos, mono, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I've compiled monodevelop for mac, version 4.1.4(build 225) and while everything seems to work, I'm getting a parser error whenever I put a server tag inside an attribute of a html tag. For example, this works:

```
<span id='test'><%=DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()%></span>
```

But this returns the parser error

```
<span id='<%=DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()%>'>test</span>
```

I've used all the latest mono runtimes, and tried C# and VB.NET projects without success. Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in MonoDevelop version 4.1.11

Comment: Hmmm... I get about 20 more errors than I was: Still can't parse server script in attributes, still can't parse Repeaters properly...

Comment: I want to add that after this got fixed, I get another error about having unclosed tags on self-closing elements, so I decided to stop using MonoDevelop, not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4287/bug-3588-nested-div-tags-throwing-parser-errors-in-html-documents

Xamarin studio seems to have the same problem as MonoDevelop. I updated both and they both broke around the same time (from memory)

The fix mentioned in the post is not in latest stable or even beta yet. I'm going to play with Alpha release, but otherwise seems you might have to go back to 4.01 from one of the comments here. Hope this helps somewhat though maybe way too late.

Comment: That got rid of 30ish of my 600 errors... seems server script tags can't be used inside a tag (to render a attribute value for example)

Comment: Can't even find 4.01 version?

Comment: Issues:

- Can't use binding expressions on ASP.NET server controls

- Can't use script tag for things like element attributes (plain html)

Comment: I can wait till they resolve the issue, I did create a bugzilla report to it, this is the url : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12832